# ndk-build installs libraries even if no change. Can this be changed?

Tags: android, python, android-ndk

I'm using the Native Development Kit (NDK) in a project of mine, and I'm trying to automate the whole app build procedure with Python.

Whenever `ndk-build` is called, it copies the prebuilt shared libraries to `libs/<abi>/`, even if there's no changes in them or they already exist there. This causes problem when I call `ant` later on, as it detects changed files (the library timestamps are newer) and so rebuilds the apk without any need.

Is there a way to change the `ndk-build` behaviour so it checks for existing libraries in the `libs/<abi>/` folder and if they need updating or some are missing, it will call `ndk-build`, otherwise, just proceed to the next build step?

I've tried using `filecmp` in Python, but as the timestamps are different between the prebuilt shared libraries and the installed ones, it doesn't work.

Comment: 1) there is __scons__, a build system written in Python 2) There is TUP, a build system that detects dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately Scons won't get around this, I need to call `ndk-build` to generate the library that the app uses. My problem lies with the `libs/<abi>` folder being refreshed every time `ndk-build` is called.

Comment: I thought about calling ndk-build conditionally. For example, you might have a TUP rule that all files in jni/ are transformed into the libraries by the command ndk-build, and another rule that res/ and src/ and libs/ are transformed into apk. Then you will call tup and it will call either ndk-build and ant or just ant.

Answer (score 0):

The OP probably doesn't need this any more, but I had the exact same problem, trying to set up a Makefile to build a project, so maybe this will be helpful to someone else in the future as well.

`ndk-build` is a wrapper around gnu make, that invokes a bunch of Makefiles in `build/core` directory of the ndk, so, while it's not universally applicable*, for your personal project you can modify those Makefiles to do whatever you want. I found a `clean-installed-binaries` target that a couple of build/install targets depended on, removing those dependencies fixed the issue with perpetual installs. 
In whichever cases that clean target is necessary you can invoke it manually with:
`ndk-build clean-installed-binaries`.

*Given the time to come up with a clean opt-in solution you can submit a patch to ndk project, and if accepted it will eventually become universally applicable.

Comment: The motivation for running `clean-installed-binaries` was, apparently, to avoid mixing release and debug binaries. I agree that it is easier to simply use this target explicitly when needed. Note that Android Studio actually forgoes the **install** step, and performs **strip** without relying on the NDK scripts, for good and for bad.